# Unable to configure TestLink using XAMPP server

Tags: configuration, testlink

I am getting the following error after configuring a user and DB details in phpadmin :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "user_login_valid_regex" on null in D:\XampServer\htdocs\TestLink\config.inc.php:364 Stack trace: #0 D:\XampServer\htdocs\TestLink\install\installNewDB.php(37): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in D:\XampServer\htdocs\TestLink\config.inc.php on line 364

URL: http://localhost/testlink/install/installNewDB.php

Unable to find the solution in google.